# G++ 5.4.0 (Ubuntu): OpenMP atomic write fails to compile

Tags: g++, openmp

Running G++ 5.4.0 with Ubuntu 16.04.4,

```
#pragma omp atomic
arr[index] = number;
```

Fails with the following error:

```
invalid form of '#pragma omp atomic' before ';' token
```

However, this should work according to the IBM open mp documentation:

```
                      .-update--.   
>>-#--pragma--omp atomic--+---------+--------------------------->
                      +-read----+   
                      +-write---+   
                      '-capture-'
```

What is going wrong here?

Comment: Curious, what kind of documentation describes this as working.

Comment: @Zulan ah, seems that the documentation is deceiving.

Comment: But where is that "image" from? You can find official documentation [here](http://www.openmp.org/wp-content/uploads/openmp-4.5.pdf).

Comment: @Zulan https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGH2K_13.1.2/com.ibm.xlc131.aix.doc/compiler_ref/prag_omp_atomic.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must specify either `read` or `write` to such a statement. The default for `omp atomic` is `update`, which is not applicable to your statement:

The valid expressions are listed in the OpenMP standard.

> If atomic-clause is read:
>
> ```
> v = x;
> ```
>
> If atomic-clause is write:
>
> ```
> x = expr;
> ```
>
> If atomic-clause is update or not present:
>
> ```
> x++;
> x--;
> ++x;
> --x;
> x binop= expr;
> x = x binop expr;
> x = expr binop x;
> ```